# Изменение регистра букв в Паскале

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Есть строка на вход в паскале. Нужно сделать так, чтобы на вывод программа выводила ту же строку, но меняла заглавные буквы на строчные, если они там были. Например, на ввод: "Окно Дверь" программа должна вывести: "окно дверь".

```
var S: string;
begin
  write('Введите текст: ');
  read(S);
  write(S);
end.
```

Comment: Можно к коду буквы прибавлять 0x20 и буква станет нижнего регистра...

Comment: Не могли бы Вы это показать, как именно это нужно прописывать?

Comment: Я не пишу на Паскале, но способ точно работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В FreePascal есть функция `AnsiLowerCase` которая конвертирует строку в нижний регистр с использованием системной локали. Определена в модуле `SysUtils`

```
uses SysUtils;

var S: string;
begin
  write('Введите текст: ');
  read(S);
  S := AnsiLowerCase(S);
  write(S);
end.
```

Comment: А если модули не работают в компиляторе? Можно ли реализовать задачу без них?

Comment: Спасибо большое. Решил вопрос с помощью LowerCase

Comment: @A.Hall `LowerCase` переводит в нижний регистр только латиницу

Comment: Возможно это какой-нибудь абс паскаль - там все не как у людей.

Comment: @Alekcvp Человек поставил тег FreePascal